# issue in MySQL query due Table name 'CASE'

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, phpmyadmin

I have installed a script from code canyon and that is having a table with the name of Case.

When I try to execute a query

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as total FROM case
```

it shows the following error

```
Static analysis:

1 errors were found during analysis.

Unexpected end of CASE expression (near "" at position 0)
SQL query: Documentation

SELECT COUNT(*) as total FROM case

MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'case' at line 1
```

I know the case is a reserved word for MYSQL but now How I can resolve this because I can't change the table name and cant modify it into whole script.

Comment: `case` is a reserved word, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_reserved_words for a full list.

Comment: Change the name of the table

Comment: I already mentioned that it's not possible to change as I have purchased this script from a website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`case` is a really poor name for a table or column name.  It is obviously a SQL keyword.  But, if you can't fix it, use backticks:

```
select count(*)
from `CASE`
```

That escapes the name and tells MySQL to treat it as the name of something, rather than the keyword.

I would encourage you to figure out how the database can be fixed.  I generally name tables in the plural -- `cases` for instance.  First, they *are* plural because they almost always have more than one row.  A side effect is that plurals conflict with many fewer keywords.